# Advanced Permalinks plugin breaks RSS

Tags: plugins

The plugin [Advanced Permalinks](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) breaks the RSS feed since Wordpress version 3.1. The developer has stopped working on the plugin, and I haven't seen any solution for it. Since my site is dependent on the plugin I can't just disable it either. Does anyone know of a way to either generate a feed differently, or of a similar plugin which could replace it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this now, answering for anyone googling.

In a recent version of Wordpress the Permalink functionality has had quite an overhaul, making Advanced Permalinks unnecessary, at least in my use case.

[More info here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others: To fix your broken categories, search the Advanced Permalinks editor for :

```
$this->add_filter ('category_rewrite_rules');
```

and add `//` at the beginning (to disable that command line)